# Does Srimad-Bhagavatam glorify the Jnana-marga?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, jnana

Srimad -Bhagataam is referred to by Sri Ramakrishna and many other saints as 'Bhakti-grantha' or a book of devotion.

Does this scripture also glorify the Jnana-marga that leads to the Formless Brahman? Kindly reply with proper reference.